# Data Frame selection of columns

Tags: r

Can someone explain me what is the meaning of these parts in the code:
-#idx in seq (where is idx coming from?)
-#temp_df$Date = row.names(temp_df) (from which data frame is selected the Date?)
-#temp_df = temp_df[c("Date", "Index", "Open", "High",
"Low", "Close", "Volume", "Adjusted")] (what is doing this command?)

```
stock_list <- c("META", "AAPL", "GOOG")
start_date <- Sys.Date()-365
end_date <- Sys.Date()
master_df <- NULL
for (idx in seq(length(stock_list))){
stock_index = stock_list[idx]
getSymbols(stock_index, verbose = TRUE, src = "yahoo", 
         from=start_date,to=end_date)
temp_df = as.data.frame(get(stock_index))
temp_df$Date = row.names(temp_df)
temp_df$Index = stock_index
row.names(temp_df) = NULL
colnames(temp_df) = c("Open", "High", "Low", "Close", 
                    "Volume", "Adjusted", "Date", "Index")
temp_df = temp_df[c("Date", "Index", "Open", "High", 
                  "Low", "Close", "Volume", "Adjusted")]
master_df = rbind(master_df, temp_df)
}
```

Comment: It is just an index to be used inside the loop, it is defined inside the loop and does not "come" from anywhere.

Comment: You can use whatever you want to index a loop. For instance `for(a in 1:3) print(df[,a])` would sequentially print the first, second, and third columns of the data frame `df`. If you changed it to `for(idx in 1:3) print(df[,idx])` it would do the exact same thing. Its just the users choice, and idx is a good choice because it reminds you that it is the index. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, `idx` doesn't come from anywhere, per se. It's declared as a temporary variable to hang on to the values of `seq(length(stock_list))` as it ticks through them. It could have been named anything. "idx" is short for index, usually meaning the current number to point to an item in the list. This is an accurate name, since `seq(n)` is the same thing as `1:n`.

The row names of `temp_df` are being copied into a new column called `Date`. See https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/row.names.html.
In this case, it looks like the data retrieved by `getSymbols()` has the date values in the place where row numbers would normally be. So, this is being copied into a regular column to make it easier to do whatever we want with it.

`temp_df[c("Date", "Index", "Open", ...)]` is a way to get the dataframe with only the specified columns, by name. However, it also gives you the columns in the order they appear in the vector, which is the purpose of it here: To rearrange the columns.

Hopefully all of that was clear enough.